# How to detect HTML elements movements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to detect when an image is moved. The point is that my page has a related HTML element (another image) to the first one that depends on its position. I though that a plugin [like Watch](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated) can help, but the only properties I know involved with position (`top` and `left`) are not changed never to this plugin (keep its original value to 'auto').

How can I get an event triggered when there is a page element move?

**UPDATE**: In order to avoid missunderstandigs, I'll explain what really happens. I have an image (call it AUX, position absolute) that is situated in function of another image position (image BASE). BASE and AUX don't share anything in the HTML except the BODY element, so it's not possible to use position relative or similar. So, I have a function that gets BASE position and computes AUX position. The problem is when the page is loaded: function is called when document is loaded and BASE has a position different from the final position (when other elements are loaded, like other images, javascript functions, etc, BASE changes its position). This makes AUX have an invalid position (it was valid, but not yet).

Comment: I miss something : How can an element move on its own ?

Comment: Basically: when other elements are loaded, the position in the document changes

Comment: Why not check the position (for example with jquery.offset) when you add the other elements or even periodically ?

Comment: That's the idea of the 'watch' plugin, but pooling is not a great idea if there are too much elements to monitor. To do it really well is not easy, so I prefer to try to find other plugins or better implementations for this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to set the position, I would use javascript to make them both a child of a minimal common element so that relative positioning schemes could be used. Because otherwise, you would need to poll for the position and update, and at best you can only do that every 10-15 ms or so.

Comment: Well, 100 ms is enough, but the problem with this is that images are "linked" to other elements and could have any value as "position". It could be very complicated to make all this to work well...